# Where is radeon(hd 7450)'s Interrupt handler in linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, isr

I'm trying to learn radeon driver with my hd 7450. IIUC, it should have a interrupt handler in its driver, but I cannot find one.

Comment: It should have multiple interrupt handlers. Where did you search? I see [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon_irq_kms.c#L55) for KMS. You could download linux sources and just `grep irq -r radeon` and find them all.

Comment: @KamilCuk, it's time to discover the `git grep ...` powerfulness along with Elixir site.